# Xamrine Http call not returning response

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, dotnet-httpclient

I wanted to fetch and display data but its not working and after this line

```
var response = await client.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

code never executed not even throw an exception

```
public async Task<List<Restresponse>> RefreshDataAsync()
{
    var Items = new List<Restresponse>();
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", string.Empty));
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); ;
           // Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TodoItem>>(content);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Debug, "EXception from restservice", e.Message);
    }
    return Items;

}
```

and i have called this functiion in OncreateView in fragment

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.recycleview, container, false);

            mRecyclerView = view.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);

            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.Activity);
            mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

            // Prepare the data source:
            listItem = new List<Restresponse>();
            try
            {
                listItem = RefreshDataAsync().Result;

                // Instantiate the adapter and pass in its data source:
                mAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(listItem, this.Activity);

                // Plug the adapter into the RecyclerView:
                mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Debug, "EXception from fragmenbt", e.Message);
            }
            return view;
        }
```

Comment: Did you add internet concection autorization ?

Comment: Also how and where is `RefreshDataAsync()` being called? If you are mixing blocking and async calls then most likely you are experiencing a deadlock.

Comment: Have you tried taking of the await and calling the code synchronously and stepping through it to make sure it works as expected? So var response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result?

Comment: i have already added permission Also RefreshDataAsync() is called in main thread i think

Comment: @NitinGupta `RefreshDataAsync().Result` is causing a deadlock do not mix blocking calls like `.Result` with async-await code as they tend to lead to deadlocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you are getting a deadlock.

If you are calling from constructor or event `RefreshDataAsync().Result;` you should remove `.ConfigureAwait(false);` from function because if you are in main thread it will never finish.

**another option after comments**
I think that if you need async process your best way is use OnResume after creating view.

```
    public async override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        try
        {
            listItem = RefreshDataAsync().Result;

            // Instantiate the adapter and pass in its data source:
            mAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(listItem, this.Activity);

            // Plug the adapter into the RecyclerView:
            mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Debug, "EXception from fragmenbt", e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Don't forget remove Try/catch block from OnCreateView where you call RefreshDataAsync()

---

Full code fragment:

```
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            try
            {
                View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.recycleview, container, false);

                mRecyclerView = view.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);

                mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.Activity);
                mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Debug, "EXception from fragment inside OnCreateView", e.Message);
            }



        }

        public async override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            // Prepare the data source:
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var uri = "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
                    var result = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
                    var Restresponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Restresponse>>(result);
                    mAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(Restresponse, this.Activity);
                    mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Debug, "EXception from fragment inside OnResume", e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have simply called RefreshDataAsync() and after executing below line control never return         var response = await client.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: and if i make a simple call its through an exception

Comment: Are you in main thread, UI thread. have you tried to remove ConfigureAwait(false)
`await client.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false) ` is recommended when you get deadlock. but if you are getting it with this sentence a deadlock may be you should try normal way without configureawait

Comment: I have removed and still the same control never return after          var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

Comment: You are calling inside an event or in page constructor?

Comment: i have update the code and i called it from fragment directly Kindly have a look

Comment: still its wont work with OnRemuse as OnReseume never executed but i have use below code  public async override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            listItem = RefreshDataAsync().Result;

            // Instantiate the adapter and pass in its data source:
            mAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(listItem, this.Activity);

            // Plug the adapter into the RecyclerView:
            mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

Comment: ans its still the same

Comment: you must remove try/catch block from OnCreateView, only must be in OnResume or OnStart if want to execute only one time

Comment: if i call this inside onclick works fine recyclebutton.Click += async delegate
            {   
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {   var uri = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
                    var result = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
                    var Restresponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Restresponse>>(result);              mAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(Restresponse, this.Activity);
                      mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter); }};

Comment: but if i call it from OnCreateView or any other Fragment function its wont work

Comment: look that on my code fragment OnResume contains async `public async override void OnResume()` this is why your button click is running correctly. Have you async added to OnResume?

Comment: i have added async already and its not working if u can check the previous comment  as well i do the same but its not working.Really strange why its not woking and wasted my 4-5 days and still ...

Comment: can u please reply how to call http onResume or onCreateView

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Can you explain a bit?

Comment: if i call this inside onclick works fine recyclebutton.Click += async delegate { using (var client = new HttpClient()) { var uri = "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";; var result = await client.GetStringAsync(uri); var Restresponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Restresponse>>(result); mAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(Restresponse, this.Activity); mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter); }};

Comment: but how to call this inside onCreateView or onActivityAttached as its not working

Comment: thanks  finally its works on OnActivityCreated method